# Unescape all nested quotes

Tags: .net, regex, string, f#, escaping

I want to unescape all nested quotes within a string. The following examples are given as literal (C# or F#) style .NET strings, not surround by quotes:

- `[(\"hello world\", 2); (\"goodbye\", 3)]` doesn't change
- `[(\"hello\"world\", 2); (\"go\"o\"d\"bye\", 3)]` becomes `[(\"hello\\\"world\", 2); (\"go\\\"o\\\"d\\\"bye\", 3)]`

I'm not sure whether this can be done with `Regex(pattern, "\\\"").Replace` but I am still too much of a regex novice for the solution to come easily to me. Any solution, regex if possible, would be appreciated.

***Edit***

Thanks for feedback so far from everyone, I see now that since there is no distinguishing between opening and closing quotes, the syntax is ambiguous and the direction I was going can't be worked. So I will give the big picture in hopes of a some new direction.

I am working on a project which converts F# Quotations into F# source code strings. So a I have function `source: Expr -> string` which should produce a string which when printed to a typical console like FSI is valid F# code. For this problem, I am looking to improve the way `Value` quotation expressions are sprinted. Currently I do something like the following (see starting at line 312 of http://code.google.com/p/unquote/source/browse/trunk/Unquote/Sprint.fs for real code):

```
match expr with
| Value(o, _) ->
  match o with
  | null -> "null"
  | _ -> sprintf "%A" o
```

But then, for example, I get the following

```
> <@ "\r\"\n" @> |> source |> stdout.WriteLine;;
"
"
"
val it : unit = ()
```

instead of the desired

```
> <@ "\r\"\n" @> |> source |> stdout.WriteLine;;
"\r\"\n"
val it : unit = ()
```

If I only needed to consider `Values` encapsulating strings, that would be easy with something like

```
let unescape s =
    ["\\","\\\\"
     "\b","\\b"
     "\n","\\n" 
     "\r","\\r" 
     "\t","\\t"
     "\"", "\\\""]
    |> List.fold (fun (s:string) (before, after) -> s.Replace(before, after)) s
```

The problem is, any object may be a `Value`, including those with structured formats used by `sprint "%A"` which I'd like to leverage as much as possible (so while I could go through and handle a finite set of cases like lists, arrays, tuples, and so forth, that isn't as general as I'd like it to be): so sprinting a `list<string*int>` `Value` needs special care for example, since we need to distinguish between quotes which should be displayed literally for string construction, versus those which should be displayed as escape sequences.

Any ideas welcome, thanks!

Comment: This is an artifact of the debugger.  The backslashes are not actually present in the string.  Use the ToCharArray() method to see for yourself.  Or the text visualizer.

Comment: Hi @Hans Passant - I'm not actually looking at debugger output at all, and am aware of the true character sequences produced by the literal strings I gave (I hope I wasn't unclear, but I truly want to replace nested quote characters with a backslash character followed by a quote character, but leave outer quote pairs unchanged).

Comment: @Stephen: what kind of syntax is this? Is the \"hello\"world\" part really valid in that syntax (it would give *"hello"world"*)?

Comment: Hi @Maxim Gueivandov - I am using C# / F# literal string syntax with escape sequences (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx). So `\"` stands for `"` (so yes, `\"hello\"world\"` would be `"hello"world"` when printed). Sorry if this is confusing, I thought using literal strings with escape sequences would make everything unambiguous.

Comment: @Stephen, I'm talking about your *[(string, int); (string, int)]* syntax, is this something of your own? I just don't recognize that structure.

Comment: @Maxim Gueivandov - ah, that's what you get when you print a list of tuples in F# using the "%A" generic formatter: (e.g. `printf "%A" [("hello world", 2); ("goodbye", 3)]`) which I want to post-process (not restricted to just lists of tuples, but any type whose structured format contains strings).

Comment: I don't think this can be done with regexs. In fact we might even need infinite lookahead. Can we assume that there are no commas within a string, i.e. does the sequence \", always end a string?

Comment: @wmeyer - unfortunately, no: we can not assume a common following a quote indicates a closing quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done as the question stands currently, because the syntax you want to process is ambiguous. For example, it is not possible to tell whether:

> `[ (\"hello\"world\", 2); (\"good\"bye\", 3)]`

Should be turned into list with two elements:

> `[ (\"hello\\\"world\", 2); (\"good\\\"bye\", 3)]`

.. or a list with just single element (with text containing some funky symbols):

> `[ (\"hello\\\"world\\\", 2); (\\\"good\\\"bye\", 3)]`

It seems that you're trying to do something with the output printed by F# Interactive. Maybe there is some better way to print what you need so that you can avoid ambiguity. Could you add some big picture?

If you need to process any list/tuple data structure, then it will be probably easier to write it using F# reflection API (see `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection` namespace) than by parsing F# output. (Or you can use the API to write your own unambiguous printer)

Comment: Hi @Tomas - that makes sense, I see now that since there is no distinguishing between opening and closing quotes, the syntax is hopelessly ambiguous. I will gladly edit my question shortly to give the big picture.

Comment: Ok - I edited question with big picture, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Thanks @Tomas - if I ever follow up on this feature, I am going to take your advice and implement a custom generic printer using reflection.